# How to match all words of one column against words in another column?

Tags: mysql, pattern-matching

I have two tables.

- Table `A`:

  ```
  Company_name
  -------------------------------
  Tata consultancy 
  Infosys tech
  Atm service
  Air force firm
  ```
- Table `B`:

  ```
  Company1_name                    |  Id
  --------------------------------   -----
  Atm and service.                 |   1
  Honey tech.                      |   2
  Tata & consultancy.              |   3
  Graft soft.                      |   4
  Atm, service.                    |   5
  ```

I want this result:

```
Id
----
1
3
5
```

Description:

> For each `Company_name` in table `A`, find a row in table `B` whose `company1_name` value has all the words from table `A`'s value, and return the matching row's `Id`.

How to design a query for this in MySQL?